# How do I pass a UDF scalar function into a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, parameters, user-defined-functions

Trying to put a function call that returns an int into a call for a stored procedure.

Getting "Incorrect syntax near '.'."

```
usp_Document_ReserveForGrader '98832750-142F-4623-91F7-6E43C6F1A963',
12,dbo.Workflow_FirstProgress()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to assign the result of the UDF to a variable and pass the variable to the PS:

```
declare @x int;
set @x = dbo.Workflow_FirstProgress();
exec usp_Document_ReserveForGrader '98832750-142F-4623-91F7-6E43C6F1A963', 12,@x;
```